# How record thumbnail when stream start NGINX RTMP

Tags: video, nginx, stream, screenshot, rtmp

we can use this :

exec_record_done ffmpeg -i /streams_video/$filename -vcodec png -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 240x120 -ss 00:00:01 -y /thumbnails/$basename.png;

this command make thumbnail, but only when recording done.

How we can make thumbnail when recording start?

Comment: I searched whole web, but nothing find.
               

after maybe 5 hours of finding solution, i found it!
             

if you what to make thumbnails at stream start add this to your app configuration:
                   

`exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/dash/$name -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 -vf scale=240:120 /docker-volume/$name.png;`